# Date format for Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I'm trying to import date in a json response. Here is the response:

```
{
     start_date: "2014-09-22",
     end_date: "2014-09-28"
}
```

I tried several date formats:

```
yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss’Z’
yyyy-MM-dd
```

However, the first one gives me `null` in the database. The second one gives me a wrong date. Actually, after I convert it back to a readable date (in the database, it is unix time - I use [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) page to convert it), the year is 1983:

```
Tue, 27 Sep 1983 22:00:00 GMT
```

How can I get the correct date?

Here is the core data model:
[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the codes, you wrote to convert json response to date. It will give good idea of the issue.

Comment: Hi, I used Magical Record to import automatically. Here is the snippet:`[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                [Country importFromObject:responseObject inContext:localContext];
            }];`

Comment: The second date formatter you mentioned seems to be working for me. You could also try `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd`.

Comment: @lenhhoxung: snippet where you tried yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss’Z’ OR 
yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: @rebello95 still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After checking, I find out something interesting. The start time and end time in the database (core data) is not wrong. When I query the object by method `findFirstWithPredicate`, it returns correct dates. I guess Apple has changed the landmark to calculate time so it isn't Jan 01 1970. It musts be another    value.